# AssertEquals is failing although it shouldnt

Tags: servlets, junit

What am I doing wrong here? I cant see the fail here!

[image]

Comment: Nobody can see the fail here. Please paste your code and the result in the question instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: assertEquals is failing although the String are equal...

Comment: First, please do **not** use images: post the code in your question!
Second, what you're printing and what you're using is not the same thing. Try assigning both `response.getContentAsString()` and the other string into local variables and use these variables both when you're printing and inside the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the String returned by `response.getContentAsString()` has a new line at the end while your expected String has not.

One way to verify this would be the following check:

```
assertEquals(
    response.getContentAsString().length()
     "{ ... }".length()
}
```

If the length is different then it is a hint that there are some invisible characters.

Answer (score 0):

the response.getContentString() is having a newline character at the end. If you want to ignore the extra spaces then You can use the **java.lang.String.trim()** operation to remove the extra spaces at the end to the expectedValue string and shall compare actual and expected.

e.g
assertEquals(response.getcontentString().**trim**(),new String("................."))

if you are sure that your method will return string with new line character and you want to test with that character then you can add a new line character with the actual string at the end.

e.g
assertEquals(response.getcontentString(),new String(".................**\n**"))